# AttributeError: module 'mysql.connector' has no attribute 'connect' using mysql-python-connector

Tags: python, mysql, spyder, anaconda3

actually I was using mysql-python connector using code below

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='passw',
                              host='localhost',database='dhruv_12')
cnx.close()
```

but when I executed the above code, it shows a error as below

```
  File ~\Desktop\I.P class 12\practical file class 12\untitled0.py:3 in <module>
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='tiger',

AttributeError: module 'mysql.connector' has no attribute 'connect'
```

I reinstalled python , reinstalled python-mysql-connector using pip and even tried changing file name but nothing happen .
I executed same code in python IDLE , it worked properly . But it doesn't worked in spyder . My spyder version is up to date . Please help me with this , I really need help because of my project
at school. Please help me as soon as possible , Its my request....

Answer (score 0):

Try importing connect as shown below.

Use a with statement to automatically close the connection.

```
"""Demonstrates creating a database connection and inserting and reading data."""

from mysql.connector import connect, Error

class SqlTest:
    """Demo class to connect, insert, and query data from a database."""

    def __init__(self, db_host, db_port, db_name, db_user_name, db_password):
        """Initialize object properties."""
        # Fields
        self._db_port = db_port
        self._db_name = db_name
        self._db_host = db_host
        self._db_user_name = db_user_name
        self._db_password = db_password
        self.db_connection = None

        # Constants
        self.SELECT_ALL = 'SELECT id, item, count FROM items'
        self.INSERT = 'INSERT INTO items (item, count) VALUES(%s, %s)'


    def insert_item(self, item, count):
        try:
            with connect(
                host=self._db_host,
                user=self._db_user_name,
                password=self._db_password,
                database=self._db_name,
                port=self._db_port
            ) as connection:
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute(self.INSERT, (item, count))
                connection.commit() # Very important!
                cursor.close()


        except Error as e:
            print(e)


    def query_all(self):
        results = None
        try:
            with connect(
                host=self._db_host,
                user=self._db_user_name,
                password=self._db_password,
                database=self._db_name,
                port=self._db_port
            ) as connection:
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute(self.SELECT_ALL)
                results = cursor.fetchall()

        except Error as e:
            print(e)

        return results
```